# Need guidance on creating an Apps script or Sheets formula to match sub-sheet names to a list of unique IDs

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

More detailed information here. I have a list of 16 workbooks with a list of sub-sheets in them organized by last name, numbering anywhere from 15-100 names per workbook. Each person has a unique ID number that needs to be placed in their respective sub-sheet. I have a separate file with the names and IDs that need to be inserted. I need to create either a script or a sheets formula that:

Iterates over all the sub-sheets, gets the sheet name, finds the name and ID in the other file, inserts the ID into a cell in the correct sub-sheet and then moves on to the next sheet in the workbook. I am very new to Sheets and scripting so I am quite lost. There is a compounding issue as well:

- the sub-sheets are not organized uniformly and are in a mixed format, most are just last name but where duplicate last names exist various conventions are used (ex: Smith, F_Smith, John Smith, are all used within a workbook to refer to 3 different people)

Since I have a list of all the IDs and people I need this is not a huge deal as the script can just match based on the last name and I can manually change the duplicates.

[Here is an anonymized sheet with sample names and IDs](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18AFpo8vpd7g5ffEEhqBBZZXAmg15lE3q41KbsBosa6w/edit?usp=sharing)

[Here is an example sheet with last names as sub-sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1j2VX_HTromOcsRrjDyxqUAu5_YebLor0jXXbba2wIt0/edit?usp=sharing)

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Updated with table for Names and IDs sheet:

| First Name | Last Name | ID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Dave | Smith | 247 |
| Jack | Smith | 248 |
| Jane | Doe | 143 |
| Evelyn | Borca | 1292 |
| Cherie | Tenny | 1148 |
| Brent | Brooks | 285 |

Screenshot of workbook with sub-sheets that needs ids inserted based on last name match - https://i.ibb.co/Ydpqvyn/workbook-example.jpg

Comment: Use [tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to show your data structure. If you share spreadsheets, do note that [your email address can be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/).

Comment: Thanks for the info about tables, I'll keep that in mind. I'm using a throwaway email as well but you are right.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function loademplidsintheresheets() {
  const niss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('nissid');
  const sh = niss.getSheetByName('Names and Ids');//spreadsheet with names and id
  const vs = sh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  let ids = { pA: [] };//ids object
  let cnt = { pA: [] };//names count object
  vs.forEach(r => {
    if(!cnt.hasOwnProperty(r[1])) {
      cnt[r[1]]=1;
      cnt.pA.push(r[1]);
    } else {
      cnt[r[1]] += 1;
    }
  });
  vs.forEach(r => {
    if(!ids.hasOwnProperty(r[1])) {
      if(cnt[r[1]] > 1) {
        ids[`${r[0].charAt(0)}_${r[1]}`] = r[2];//if cnt > 1
      } else {
        ids[r[1]] = r[2];//in last name is unique
      }
    }
  });
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();//assume spreadsheet ids are in the active spreadsheet
  const wsh = ss.getSheetByName('Spreadsheeds and Ids');
  const [hA,...wbs] = wsh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const idx ={};
  hA.forEach((h,i) => idx[h]=i);
  wbs.forEach(r =>{
    let twb = SpreadsheetApp.openById(r[idx['id header']]);
    twb.getSheets().forEach(s => {
      s.getRange('A1Notation for the cell you want the id in').setValue(ids[sh.getName()]);
    });
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the solution, I will try it and pick it apart so I understand it better. Thanks for your time.

Comment: A little confused about this section here:
`const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();//assume spreadsheet ids are in the active spreadsheet
  const wsh = ss.getSheetByName('Spreadsheeds and Ids');
  const [hA,...wbs] = wsh.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  const idx ={};
  hA.forEach((h,i) => idx[h]=i);
  wbs.forEach(r =>{
    let twb = SpreadsheetApp.openById(r[idx['id header']]);
    twb.getSheets().forEach(s => {
      s.getRange('A1Notation for the cell you want the id in').setValue(ids[sh.getName()]);
    });
  })
}`
Sub-sheet IDs in their own sheet? Unsure about 'id header'.

Comment: id header is the string a the top of the id column in row 1 which I assumed to be the header row

Comment: Hi MiMi, no matter what I put for the id header I get an error on the 'id header' line of code when trying to run the script on my example files. I don't fully understand what the last part of the script is doing. Do I need to create a sub-sheet with the sheet IDs of the sheets I want to iterate through and then put the string of the header row in the id header portion?

Comment: Well at this point I think I would need to know more about what you are trying to accomplish.  However, I do not like to follow links to other accounts because it exposes our email addresses and in some cases the links cannot be removed.  So I will not follow those links.  Which requires you to share data about you question in screen shots of your spreadsheets and sharing data through the use of data tables.  If you wish more help please provide me with more information.

Comment: No worries, I understand, thanks. I have updated the initial questions with a table for the names and IDs worksheet and screenshot of the spreadsheet that needs the IDs matched and inserted. I was kept getting an 'unexpected property or method' error for the line with the id header. I was doing something wrong or my data didn't match what you wrote.